# Map two different lists

Tags: python

I'm in a pickle.

I'm searching for headers and footers inside a dd.

When I find a header, I put it in inside a list - same is true for footers.

However I noticed that sometimes a footer is found before a header, in that case I check if headerlist is empty, if it is, ignore the footer. 
This works fine.

```
   if not header:
       footer.append(myfooter)
```

However sometimes I find a header, then two footers, then a header again. These are then added to a list - which is not what I'm aiming for.

My goal is to map headers with footers as long as they come directly after one and another. Therefore the two lists should always have the same amount OR the headerlist should be bigger than the footerlist.

Any ideas how to implement an algorithm accordingly?

Comment: it sounds similar to balancing parentheses to me. One of the simplest solution is by using  stack https://interactivepython.org/runestone/static/pythonds/BasicDS/SimpleBalancedParentheses.html

Comment: So, you want for every found header map it to the first unused (not already mapped) footer found after the header. Right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only add a footer to the list if the last seen item was a header. Is that what you want to do?

Comment: Solved it by adding booleans that gets true when header is found, and in the footer statement, check if this header is true, OR if header is not empty (as we can find header, header) Do you think that is a good solution? @Moberg

Comment: Yes I think so. :)

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want? I'm not sure what a 'dd' is, and I pretend that headers and footers are single lines that begin in a particular way. You will need to replace the logic that matches headers and footers to suit your use-case.

```
import re

VALID_DOCUMENT_A = \
"""
header: 1
Hi there.
This is the body of page 1.
footer: 1
header: 2
This is the second page.
footer: 2
"""

VALID_DOCUMENT_B = \
"""
header: 1
Hi there.
This is the body of page 1.
footer: 1
header: 2
This is the second page.
footer: 2
header: 3
This third page has a header but no footer.
"""

INVALID_DOCUMENT_A = \
"""
header: 1
Hi there.
This is the body of page 1.
footer: 1
This is the second page. Where's the header, though?
footer: 2
"""

INVALID_DOCUMENT_B = \
"""
header: 1
Hi there.
This is the body of page 1.
footer: 1a
footer: 1b
This is the second page. Oops - two footers above.
footer: 2
"""

INVALID_DOCUMENT_C = \
"""
header: 1
Hi there.
This is the body of page 1.
footer: 1
header: 2a
header: 2b
This is the second page. Oops - two headers above.
footer: 2
"""


def is_header(line):
    return re.match('^header:.*', line)


def is_footer(line):
    return re.match('^footer:.*', line)


def pair_headers_and_footers(text):
    lines = text.splitlines()

    stack = []
    for i, line in enumerate(lines, 1):
        if is_header(line):
            if stack:
                raise ValueError('Got unexpected header on line {}'.format(i))

            stack.append(line)

        elif is_footer(line):
            if not stack:
                raise ValueError('Got unexpected footer on line {}'.format(i))

            yield stack.pop(), line


if __name__ == '__main__':
    documents = [
        VALID_DOCUMENT_A,    # 2 headers, 2 footers
        VALID_DOCUMENT_B,    # 3 headers, 2 footers
        INVALID_DOCUMENT_A,  # missing header for page 1
        INVALID_DOCUMENT_B,  # multiple footers for page 1
        INVALID_DOCUMENT_C   # multiple headers for page 2
    ]

    for document in documents:
        try:
            print(list(pair_headers_and_footers(document)))
        except ValueError as e:
            print(e)
```

**Output**

```
[('header: 1', 'footer: 1'), ('header: 2', 'footer: 2')]
[('header: 1', 'footer: 1'), ('header: 2', 'footer: 2')]
Got unexpected footer on line 7
Got unexpected footer on line 6
Got unexpected header on line 7
```

**Addendum**

I should add that in the function `pair_headers_and_footers`, you can replace:

```
lines = text.splitlines()
```

With:

```
lines = (m.group(0).rstrip() for m in re.finditer('(.*\n|.+$)', text))
```

This might be useful to help reduce memory usage, especially if you're processing large bodies of text. With this modification, the whole process of pairing headers and footers becomes "lazy".

Comment: Many thanks for your input, maybe it was too advanced for me, but the other answer suited my way of thinking better. I'm still pretty new to Python

Comment: @user7440299 No worries, whatever helps you best mate.